# Where can I find visualizations of quantum field theory equations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, software, visualization

As I work through A. Zee's "Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell," I'd love to be able to visualize the different equations so I can explore the effects of different terms.  Any suggestions? Python script, Matlab, Mathematica, or are there any tools or videos already out there that cover this subject?

Comment: Which equations?

Comment: There's a [Royal Institution lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNVQfWC_evg) with a visualisation at about 23mins of empty space according to QFT that may be of interest?

Comment: I've been looking for visualisations as well, it's surprisingly hard to find. You can of course go through the work yourself with Mathematica or numerically in python with scipy/numpy (the latter being free software). If you do, please post nice graphs somewhere google can find them ;)

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty of visualizing a quantum field comes from the large number of degrees of freedom it has: Even if you discretize the field to a 2-dimensional mattress of, e.g., $100\times100$ points each of which can only oscillate in one dimension (similar to how Zee does it in one of the entry examples of his book), you already need a state function $\Psi: \mathbb R^{10\,000} \to \mathbb C$ (i.e. from a 10 000 dimensional real space to the complex plane).

One way of visualizing such a high dimensional function is to use a parallel axes diagram and plot only a relatively small number of randomly chosen points.

You can see how the result looks like in this paper:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321684743_A_new_way_of_visualizing_quantum_fields

Best regards
Helmut

Comment: Link-only answers are not really good. Could you summarize the main points here?